# How to add an option in an optionset of contact form dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I've seen examples online on how to add a new option to a global optionset in C#, but my optionset is not global, I only use it for the contact form as a dropdownlist, how can I add a new option in C#?

Comment: why you can't add the value under customizations with CRM UI?

Comment: I'm importing data from a sheet, the field could contain unexpected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [InsertOptionValueRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.insertoptionvaluerequest.aspx) to insert a new option value for a global or local option set. To make it available to users, you have to publish the change by using PublishXmlRequest.

To perform this action, the caller must have privileges listed in [InsertOptionValue message privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334599.aspx)

When you update a global option set only Label and OptionSetName are required.

When you update a local option set only AttributeLogicalName, EntityLogicalName, and Label are required.